# A toy company produces a faulty item with a $4\%$ probability. The production control system discards a faulty item with a $99\%$ probability

Tags: probability

A toy company produces a faulty item with a $4\%$ probability. The production control system discards a faulty item with a $99\%$ probability. Compute the probability that, out of $5$ toys, at least one is faulty and it is not discarded by the production control system.

I know from the textbook that the answer is $0,1998\%$, but I can't find the right way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that a given toy is faulty and not discarded is $$p=.04\cdot.01=.0004$$

The probability that out of $5$ toys, at least one is faulty but not discarded is $$1-(1-p)^5\approx.0019984$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

First compute the probability of having exactly $1$ defective toy that is not discarded

Then compute the probability of having exactly $2$ defective toys, at least one of which is not discarded (which equals the chance of having exactly $2$ defective toys minus the probability of having exactly $2$ defective toys, both of which are discarded)

repeat for having exactly $3$, $4$, and $5$ defective toys.

Add

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan No ... you can have a bunch of defective toys, all of which are being discarded. So that would not be included in the $P(0$ defective toys discarded), but you also do not want it in the 'desired' event of having at least one defective toy not being discarded.